# android java onSearchRequested() called for DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_LOCAL

Tags: java, android, search

I've successfully implemented what I believe is the most modern available search interface based on:

Including a `searchable.xml` in the `xml` resource directory, setting up the manifest to have

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value=".SearchActivity"
/>
```

in the activity declaration for every activity that has the "Search" menu item.

Creating an activity to implement that `SearchActivity` whose manifest entry has

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.searchable"
    android:resource="@xml/searchable"
/>
```

Creating a custom suggestion provider.

Writing a method to configure the search view using `SearchManager`, `SearchView` and `SearchView.OnSuggestionListener`.

Adding

```
app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
```

to the "Search" menu item in my overflow menu.

Everything works perfectly ... except the search that results when

```
setDefaultKeyMode(Activity.DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_LOCAL)
```

is in the `onCreateView` of every fragment which supports search and the user starts typing on a hardware keyboard.

What happens then is that the old style `SearchDialog` is displayed (the one with a back arrow and the app icon on the left of the input field). That shows the same suggestion list (styled as I styled it), but tapping on a suggestion doesn't call any methods in my `SearchView.OnSuggestionListener`, and so although it does invoke my `SearchActivity`, it shows everything in the suggestion list, not the specific suggestion I tapped on.

For context, the modern search UI that shows up when I use the "Search" menu item has a back arrow, a search icon, the input field and a voice search icon. My app doesn't have to field the "Search" menu item except to return "false" from the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method.

If were to guess, I'd say the OS is calling `onSearchRequested()` in response to typing. I'm guessing that because if I mod my code to call that method in response to the "Search" menu item, I get the same result.

Does anyone know how to make the system use the modern search interface I've set up in the case of typing with `setDefaultKeyMode(Activity.DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_LOCAL)` in force?